# Visual Studio Xamarin Forms App cannot launch on iPhoneSimulator

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ios-simulator

I have a bunch of apps that launch just fine. One that doesn't and it was downloaded from the Microsoft website when going through the Azure tutorial. When debugging on the iphonesimulator on a remote mac I get:

> error HE0046: Failed to install the app
>   'com.xamarin.sample.smallmobileapp' on the device 'iOS 11.3 (15E217) -
>   iPad Air 2': lstat of
>   /Users/monsieur/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/smallmobileapp.iOS/01bbf475e45afc9c75bdb4bb54d7386e/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/smallmobileappiOS.app
>   failed: No such file or directory         0

I navigated to the folder and found:

[image: error pic]

I have tried deleting obj/ bin files, resetting the ios provisioning, cleaning the solution /rebuilding. NothingJust a a know jerk reaction but I realise it's a prob mac side.

Any ideas how best to fix this? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleted the folder:

> /Users/monsieur/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/smallmobileapp.iOS/

Redeployed to iphonesimulator.

All good! Looked into the no entry sign on top of files, looks like it's got something to do with access. Kids use the mac so maybe I inadvertently did the first build under a different account. Anyway, all good now.